# Attempting to autheticate

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

In a school network there are 28 computers with Windows 10 installed. They are connected to the internet via Wireless through a TP-Link Wireless router. 2 computers refuse to connect to the internet. Trying to connect to the SSID blocks the Wi-Fi connection in Network and Sharing Centre on "Attempting to autheticate". Trying to ping other computers on the network gives me "PING: Transmit failed. General failure.". I've tried giving them static IPs and I also deactivated the installed antivirus. Moving the wireless stick in different USB locations gives me "Unable to connect to this network". What could be the issue ?

Comment: Check the logs on the WiFi router. Check the password on the computers. Check the config on the WiFi router, especially for limits on the number of concurrent clients.

Comment: The router does not have logs active. When connecting, I am not prompted with a password request. I only have 1 computer with a working connection right now.

Comment: I fixed the issue. The password on the computers was wrong. Thank you for the help.